# Django models filter query not recognising field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am working on a Django project, filter query function is not working as expected

I imported the model, did migration
I don't understand where the code is wrong, it is not able to recognize the field (rating)

Model I created

```py
class Problem(models.Model):
    contestID = models.IntegerField()
    index = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True,related_name="Problme")
```

My code in views: ( object.all() is working properly but the filter is not working)

```py
def fetchProblems(min = 0, max = 5000, filter = False):

    if not filter:
        problemSet = Problem.objects.all().values()
    else:
        problems = Problem.objects.filter(rating < max,rating > min)

        
    return problemSet
```

My error : ( rating not defined) (basically I tried all fields it shows all not defined)

```py
NameError: name 'rating' is not defined
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Please do not upload images of code / errors, [edit] your question and add them as _text_ formatted as code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
.filter(rating__gt=min)
```

You can find out more about the various lookup types (separated by double underscores) over at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups